# Move search image to right of text box?

Tags: css, asp.net, textbox

I am trying to place a search icon at the right of a text box. But I can only get it to display on the left.

Any ideas? Also, why are the left hand side lines of the text box darker than the other 2 sides?...It isn't the image I tried resizing it and still the same.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_Coords" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="searchIcon"/>

.searchIcon {background-image: url('/Images/HeaderSpriteSheet.png'); background-color: transparent; background-repeat: no-repeat; display: inline; float: left;  width: 32px; height: 32px; background-position: 0px -384px; }[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: Gonna need some more details, before you get downvoted...

Answer (score 0):

Change your css class as below,

```
.searchIcon {
    background-image: url('/Images/HeaderSpriteSheet.png'); 
    background-color: transparent; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;       
    width: 32px; 
    height: 32px; 
    background-position: right center; 
}
```